# How do you bind to the property of a User Control?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

In Windows Store Apps, you create a user control to encapsulate and reuse code-behind and layout XAML. A simple user control might look like this:

```
<UserControl>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="First Name" />
        <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Now, I want to setup binding. So I create code-behind with properties that expose the Text properties of the UI controls. Something like this:

```
public string TextBoxText
{
    get { return MyTextBoxText.Text; }
    set { MyTextBoxText.Text = value; }
}
```

However, this does not work. It seems like data binding to a user control is a valuable part of a XAML UI. But how is it accomplished?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is only one implementation of a property in a user control that supports binding in the consuming page. That is a dependency property. The implementation is simple enough, but you must also include the changed event to interact directly with the UI, since a dependency property is a static property on a control. Like this:

```
public string TextBoxText
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(TextBoxTextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TextBoxTextProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBoxTextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("TextBoxText", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl),
    new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnTextBoxTextPropertyChanged));

private static void OnTextBoxTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    (d as MyUserControl).MyTextBox.Text = e.NewValue.ToString();
}
```

I admit, this is not super obvious. But hopefully now that you know, it will save you hours of searching and trying to figure out. Again, you can only bind to a dependency property of a user control. And, you can only set the UI values off the static thread using the changed event.

Best of luck!

Comment: The only actual binding is by the parent of the user control binding to the property of the user control. Like `<UI:MyControl TextBoxText="{Binding Somepath}" />`.

Comment: How would you associate an event like Tapped with an ICommand?  Like this? `        public static readonly DependencyProperty LogoutCommandProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("LogoutCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MyUserControl), null);
        private void PathLogout_Tapped(
            object sender, 
            Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            LogoutCommand?.Execute(null);`

Answer (score 0):

You always talk about binding - but you don't actually bind the textbox.textproperty to your property (you set it).

If you wanna use binding, create a dependency property and bind the text-property of the textbox this way:

```
<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" **Text="{Binding TextBoxText, Mode=TwoWay}"** />
```

Don't forget to set the usercontrols DataContext property to the usercontrol-instance:

```
public MyUserControl1()
{
  this.InitializeComponent();

  // Set the datacontext to the usercontrol-instance.
  // If you don't, the binding will use the usercontrol's parent-datacontext.
  this.DataContext = this;
}
```

Comment: So, the reason your approach does not work is because the parent of the `user control` is not binding to the `TextBoxText` **property** of the `user control`, it is binding to the `TextBoxText` **dependency property** of the `user control`. The `user control` TextBox is binding to the `TextBoxText` property, though. It's a mismatch. As a result, even if you implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the `TextBoxText` **property**, the `TextBoxText` **dependency property** would not raise the event and so the binding, in your sample, would not update in the UI. You should test it.

Comment: how embarrassing ... thank you for the hint. i only tested it one way! thanks!